# Why are new lines added to THREE.Line not rendered, despite setting verticesNeedUpdate?

Tags: three.js

When I push points to my geometry after (!) `renderer.render()` was called, the new lines are not displayed. I am setting `geometry.verticesNeedUpdate` to true, as suggested.

Minimal example:
https://jsfiddle.net/y2374dr1/9/

Note: Remove the first renderer.render() call to see all lines.

Is this a bug in THREE.js, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: After calling render(), the verticesNeedUpdate flag has changed from true to false. This seems correct.

Comment: The code is not really relevant since the actual problem is expressed in the first sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a `three.js` bug. First of all, you are using an outdated version of `three.js` (`R60`) which is several years old. I've updated the fiddle so it uses the latest version `R113` and the latest supported API. Besides, it's important to know that `THREE.Geometry` is somewhat deprecated. It is internally converted to `THREE.BufferGeometry`. During this process, vertex buffer of a certain size are allocated. Since these buffers are fixed size (it's not possible to resize them), you see no effect of your vertex additions. You have to create a new geometry instead, so the renderer internally creates a new instance of `THREE.BufferGeometry`.

For beginners, this is quite confusing. Hence, I recommend to completely avoid `THREE.Geometry` and focus on `THREE.BufferGeometry` instead. The restriction of using fixed-sized buffers becomes more obvious then. When working with `THREE.BufferGeometry`, you have to create sufficiently sized buffers in the first place that are large enough to hold all upcoming vertex additions. Otherwise you have to delete and recreate buffers which is however an expensive operation.

https://jsfiddle.net/nqveab8y/1/

`three.js R113`

Comment: To add to the answer: Mugen87 used "line.geometry = geometry.clone();" as a workaround to make the example work with THREE.Geometry.